# Logged in as shows only one value

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my form to show as who am i logged in. I have login form and when you type in password and username it opens phonebook form where i want, besides all else, a label to show username that i entered, now it only shows Role, which i enter in signup form

```
 public partial class PhoneBook : Form
    {
        Thread th;
        private string Role;
        SqlConnection con = Helper.GetConnectionStringDatabase();
        public PhoneBook(string role)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Role = role;
        }

        private void Biodata_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ActiveControl = tbName;
            tbName.Focus();
            Display();
            LoggedAs.Text = "You are logged in as: " + Role;
            if (Role != "Admin\t")
            {
                btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

and here is login code

```
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //CheckForDatabaseExistance();

            using (SqlConnection con = Helper.GetConnectionStringDatabase())
            {

                SqlDataAdapter sda =
                    new SqlDataAdapter(
                        "SELECT Role FROM LOGIN WHERE UserName='" + tbUser.Text + "' AND Password='" + tbPassword.Text +
                        "' ", con);

                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            CheckIfTxtBoxexAreNotEmpty();

            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    PhoneBook ss = new PhoneBook(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                    ss.Show();
                }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your username and password");
                tbUser.Clear();
                tbPassword.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code for the login form is needed to get into how things are working in here.

Comment: I updated question :)

Comment: Just by the way google for `Sql injection` and care for escaping your username and password. With this code I could login without knowing any credentials.

Comment: You might want to push this code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get more understanding of basics..

Comment: @Bopa Oh I missed one thing in my answer. Edit incoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select your username in this line:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter
(
    // Pick the right username-column
    "SELECT Role, Username FROM LOGIN WHERE UserName='" + tbUser.Text + "' AND Password='" + tbPassword.Text +
"' ", con);
```

Then modify the constuctor like this:

```
private string Role;
private string User;
public PhoneBook(string role, string user)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Role = role;
    User = user;
}
```

Then just correct your call:

```
PhoneBook ss = new PhoneBook(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[1][0].ToString());
```

OR

```
PhoneBook ss = new PhoneBook(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```

*Dont know about the index*

You are done then. Your `User` in `PhoneBook` will have its username. You can then simply replace `Role` with `User`:

```
private void Biodata_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = tbName;
    tbName.Focus();
    Display(); //                               |
    //                                          v Here
    LoggedAs.Text = "You are logged in as: " + User + " - " + Role;
    if (Role != "Admin\t")
    {
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I want it to show both 'Role' and 'User' :)

Comment: Can i ask you one more question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970398/passing-valus-for-database-to-form)

Comment: @Bopa If this solved your problem, consider marking it with the hook right under the voting-buttons. Then sure, I can have a fast look into it.

Comment: Oh sry, I'm new to stackoverflow